# Aggregation relationships (two or more) between two tables in laravel 5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I am developing a web app using laravel 5. Now i am having a issue below:

- I have two table users and feedbacks

  - users: id, username, password
  - feedbacks: id, provider, receiver, reviewer, content
- I want to provider, receiver and reviewer is a user. Meaning i will storage user'id into provider, receiver and reviewer.
- In laravel, i only can setup a relationship for model User like: `$this->belongsTo('User', 'provider', 'id')`
- And i want to receiver and reviewer also have belongsTo relationship
- I thought creating the third table for many to many relationship, but if i do it, i must create two tables for receiver and reviewer.

I need helping to solve this issue without using more queries on controller, thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your **feedbacks Model** create the following relations:

```
public function provider()
{
    $this->belongsTo('User', 'provider', 'id');
}

public function reviewer()
{
    $this->belongsTo('User', 'reviewer', 'id');
}

public function receiver()
{
    $this->belongsTo('User', 'receiver', 'id');
}
```

Comment: Yes, it worked. I thought the function's name for relationship must match with table's name, so i was wrong.